# Show Post columns to specific users on condition

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, custom-field

I have a CPT called Topics. And admin or editor can only make topics and It can be assigned to authors. I have a meta box where there will be a list of authors and Admin/Editor can choose whom to assign the Topic. So the assigned topic will be used by authors to write the post. But what I wanted was to show only the Topics only to the author that I have assigned. If a post is assigned to author1 I don't want author2 to see to use that. So, the author name will be in meta box and in the Topic CPT column. So, my condition would be 
`if($get_current_user == get_post_meta( $post_id, 'cruiser_writer_value_key', true )){
}`
[image: Topics CPT]

So as you can see in the picture. There are three users and I just want Author2 to see the post assigned to him. How can I hide the post columns to authors if it has not been assigned to them. But admin should see all the post.

Comment: first of all use == instead of =, the later one always return true, and use && instead. if(($get_current_user == $writer_list_value) and ($writer_list_value == get_post_meta( $post_id, 'cruiser_writer_value_key', true )))

Comment: Hey, I am really sorry for the Typo there. It was just during this question I hadn't made the mistake in my actual code. Anyway, I have updated that. But my main question was how to show it only to the author that I have on the Writer field.